# jQuery Parent Sibling source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, siblings

```
<div id="cell">
   <div class="choose">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h3>Title</h3></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right"><a href="#" class="ex">CLICK HERE</a></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div class="result">
      <img src="images/blank.jpg" width="72" height="72">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my HTML, what would be the proper combination for me to click **(a.ex)** and be able to modify the img scr of **(div.result img)**?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then if you use what you have in bold as selectors, you'd be darn close on it's own...

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
$(this).closest('div.choose').next('div.result').find('img')
```

Your question is a bit vague, and as Blunderfest mentioned in the comments, you could select the image directly with `div.result img`